# cshtml modal calling JS function on close

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using this click event to open a modal that will let the user edit the form. It open fine the user update the data but then once they close the modal I like to call a function that will build the data. I there a way to call a JS function that is on the parent cshtml page ?

Main page

```
$(".references-list").on("click", ".edit-reference", function () {
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    var versionKey =  '@Model.VersionKey'

    $.ajax({
        url: '/References/Edit',
        method: 'GET',
        data: { index: index, VersionKey: versionKey }, 
        begin: function () {
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#add-reference-modal .modal-body").html(data);
            $("#add-reference-modal").modal('show');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Edit cshtml page

```
<div id="container" style="@(Model.Type == "Pubmed" ? "display:block" : "display:none")">
    <form id="form" class="form-horizontal" data-sortorder="@Model.SortOrder">
        <div id="search-grid-container" style="text-align:center;margin: 20px 0;">
            @(Model.Text)
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="font-size:smaller">Regimen References</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10" style="font-size:smaller">
               @Html.Partial("RegimenReferences", (ReferencesModel)Model)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary modal-submit-btn">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modal-close-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the modal html.To clarify, the edit page is inside the modal correct?

Comment: yes I have the edit.cshtml page that is the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the modal is defined in the parent page, you could attach an event to modal close. From there, you could use the modal as the starting point and use .find() on your input fields to get the data.

Just add this to your parent page script;

```
$('#add-reference-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   var property1 = $(this).find("#yourElementId1").val();
   var property12 = $(this).find("#yourElementId2").val();
   callFunction();

   // ... do something else
});
```